# -> java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset

Tags: jdbc, oracle10g, netbeans-7, resultset

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    if (evt.getSource() == jButton1) {

        String ab = jTextField1.getText();
        String bc = jPasswordField1.getText().toString();
        String cd = jTextField2.getText();
        String de = jTextField3.getText();
        PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "hr");
            ps = c.prepareStatement("Select User_Name from AdminLogin where Password =?");
            ps.setString(1, bc);

            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            rs.next();

            if (ab.equals(rs.getString(1))) {

                ps1 = c.prepareStatement("Update AdminLogin SET Date1=?,Time=? WHERE Password=?");
                ps1.setString(1, cd);
                ps1.setString(2, de);
                ps1.setString(3, bc);
                int e = ps1.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Welcome", "Logged In", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                //MainMenuAAI mainMenuAAI = new MainMenuAAI();
                //setVisible(false);}
            } else if (!(ab.equals(rs.getString(1)))) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "<html>YOU ARE NOT A<br>ADMIN</br></html>", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                //AdminLogin admin=new AdminLogin();
                //setVisible(false);
            }

            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }// TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Everything is working fine in the code. It is executing the code inside

```
if(ab.equals(rs.getString(1)))
```

and showing "Welcome" but not d one inside

```
if(!(ab.equals(rs.getString(1))))
```

Whenever I enter wrong username or password it shows the error

java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct, because if you enter wrong username or password, NO record will be returned. So, when you use the `rs.next();` in this case, it is trying to access the first row of the empty result set! And that is where it is throwing the exception.

You could fix your code like this:

```
rs = ps.executeQuery();
//rs.next();
int counter=0;
while (rs.next()) {
    counter++;
    if (ab.equals(rs.getString(1))) {
        ps1 = c.prepareStatement("Update AdminLogin SET Date1=?,Time=? WHERE Password=?");
        ps1.setString(1, cd);
        ps1.setString(2, de);
        ps1.setString(3, bc);
        int e = ps1.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Welcome", "Logged In", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        //MainMenuAAI mainMenuAAI = new MainMenuAAI();
        //setVisible(false);}
    } 
}
if(counter==0){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "<html>YOU ARE NOT A<br>ADMIN</br></html>", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: @pooja singh dont forget that you can upvote and accept an answer if it helps you